# Proguard, keep all referenced classes

Tags: java, proguard, android-proguard

Assume I have structure:

```
import some.other.Clazz;

public class A {

    Clazz clazz;
    B b;

    public class B {
        C c;
        //...
    }

    public static class C {
        //...
    }
}
```

Is there some nifty proguard trick that would allow me to **recursively** `keep` all classes that are used by my class `A`? So also all classes that are referenced internally by `B`, `C` and `Clazz`?

Comment: Can you explain why do you need such a `nifty trick`? What is your use case?

Comment: @larsgrefer Sure, I'm creating a tool that verifies that the class I need to keep in proguard has the correct proguard rule. It would be easier for me to verify the presence of a single rule for a class `A`, than to manually figure out all referenced classes and verify rule presence for all of them.

Comment: @YvetteColomb not necessarily. I am an android developer and I need a solution to my problem in Android-related scenario. So if there's a solution that will work with proguard that's configured for android and will not work for regular proguard for java, I'm fine with that. Hence the tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont think you can do that with proguard only and I really doubt there is a straightforward solution (plugin you can use) with mvn\gradle\sbt\whatever for this.

If you're ok with running code or shell commands during your build I can recommend you some building blocks but, since putting them together really depend on how you build your project I can only give basic suggestions on how to glue them together.

---

The general idea is:

**(1)** Use [jdeps](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/jdeps.html) (part of and distributed with jdk) to fetch dependencies (including transitive) from compiled `.class` files of interest.

In your case outputting recursive dependencies of `some.class` (limited to `root_package`) should be something like:

```
jdeps -v -R -e "root_package.*" some.class
```

**(2)** grab `jdeps` output and transform it into proguard config (list of classes to `-keep`).

**(3)** In your main proguard config file [include](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/proguard/manual/usage#include) config file you generated in (2).

---

Step (2) requires most legwork and can be approached differently.

My suggestion is to use whatever scripting capabilities your build system has to run `jdeps` and do output transformation.

Maven, for example, has [plugin that allows groovy scripts to be executed](https://groovy.github.io/gmaven/groovy-maven-plugin/execute.html) during build.

If you are more comfortable with running shell scripts you can do the following:

1. pipe `jdeps` output into something like:

   `grep -Po classname_regex`

   ... to keep only class names you want to keep (you can use zero-length assertions to build `classname_regex`).
2. pipe output of `grep` into something like:

   `awk '{print "-keep class " $0}`

   ... to get proguard config and save output to file.

Comment: It isn't perfect but I might be able to work with `jdeps` (of which existence I didn't know before). Thanks